# Have to click twice on a popup window/Dialog box

Tags: javascript

I am using a webkit browser and getting an bug as when I am trying to close the popup its not active only and the parent browser is active even after the pop up for uploading files is open.
I have to click on popup to activate it first and then again to make any selection on it.

How can I make the pop up active as soon as its open.

Is there a way to add event handler in the input tag only to make the pop up active and inactive the parent browser.
 for eg

```
<form action="${ctx}/home/step11/uploadReport" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_upload">
               <table style="margin-left:25px">
                   <tr>
                       <td colspan="5" style="vertical-align:middle; font-size:100%">Demo Request Upload:</td> 
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td style="vertical-align:middle"><input id="uploadFileId" name="fileName" type="file" multiple="true"/></td>

                       <td/>
                       <td>               
                           <c:if test="${empty editable}">  
                                <input id="btnImport" class="active small button" disabled="disabled" type="button" value="Import"/>   
                            </c:if> 
                            <c:if test="${not empty editable}">  
                                <input id="btnImport" class="active small button" type="button" value="Import"/>   
                            </c:if> 
                       </td>

                   </tr>
               </table>
           </form>
```

Comment: Do you have some relevant JS code you can share with us?

Comment: @DanielLisik  Can you suggest how can I make my popup active after clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an event which automatically clicks on the browser when its opened so it will be active after a couple of micro seconds